# Using a proxy for certain sites only

Tags: proxy, proxy-server

When I work from home, I want to read some sites that my work blocks.
Since I'm connected via VPN, their servers route my requests and sites like reddit are blocked.

Currently, I just RDP into another computer in my home and use the browser on that machine.
Is there a way to set up a proxy on the other computer and instruct my system to use the proxy for certain sites?

This is all on win7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use Firefox, you could use FoxyProxy to only use a configured proxy for certain sites, certain URL patterns.

Comment: I would add that FoxyProxy **Standard** is needed, as the basic version doesn't support proxy selection based on URLs.

Comment: How can I configure FoxyProxy not to use the proxy for certain websites?

Answer (score 12):

I did a lot of research and I think the most convenient way is using a PAC file.

In Firefox: open preferences and choose settings of network proxy settings.

Selecting "automatic proxy configuration" and pointing to where your PAC file resides. Don't forget to use `file:///` scheme.

Follow [mozilla's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file#dnsDomainIs(host,%20domain)) to get your whitelist running.

It will be something like:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (dnsDomainIs(host, "www.proxyThisWebsite.com")) {
        return "SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:9988";
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, powerful, and probably much more durable than any extension, since Mozilla is way more likely to be breaking them by browser updates

Comment: This does not work for a local pac file on a linux machine. I've even set this function to always return my local proxy, and my proxy never receives any requests from firefox.

Comment: @DrewNutter Maybe file wasn't found by Firefox or there's a typo in this file? Firefox will silently ignore it in this case. Proper path to the file should look like this: `file:///home/user/path/proxy.pac`.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically proxy auto configuration (PAC) script is meant for this (but this requires some programming).
Practically, I think you can use different browsers - one for sites you access via proxy and second for all other sites. In Firefox you can also set up different profiles - one for using proxy, and second for direct access to internet:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is configure your home computer to only use the VPN connection when trying to reach machines at work, otherwise forward through your local(home) router.  Presumably, you won't have to deal with any web filtering that way.

If the following link doesn't work, you can google configuring a split tunnel VPN on Win7.
https://www.isinc.com/2011/08/30/configuring-a-split-tunnel-pptp-vpn-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

Proxy SwitchyOmega https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchyomega/

1. Go to "options" and configure your proxy
2. Use it for a specific site[s] only: 
   The key is in "auto switch" tab in options -> "Switch rules" insert the name of the site for which you would like the proxy to be used for: cnn.com in this example
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a windows VPN connection, there is a check box on the ipv4 settings advanced properties window (of that connection) that (since the release of windows 7 is checked by default) forces all connections to use the 'default gateway on remote network'. Un-check this box and you should be able to navigate to any address. This may require you to specify a domain when you rdp into a machine in your office (i.e. machine.domain.com).