# How do I proxy just certain sites?

Tags: vpn, proxy, bittorrent, transmission, private-browsing

Time Warner has apparently blocked access to trackers that are used by thepiratebay. I need to bypass this somehow, but I don't need to bypass everything. Turns out after downloading the initial torrent info Time Warner doesn't block the rest of the download.

I assume this means I only need to proxy/VPN/etc. the magnet link or the tracker connection. I know about [one similar superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/417896/using-a-proxy-for-certain-sites-only), but it didn't seem to help. Anyone have some ideas to get me started?

Comment: You can always set up your torrenting program to use a proxy.

Comment: I'm new to using proxies, but I did set a free proxy up in ktorrent and it didn't seem to help. Are proxies enough to get around the issue?