# how to automatically detect whether to use proxy or not

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy

here is the situation, I work with a bunch of non-tech sales people, they sometimes require to access a set of `private services` that should only work within the office.

so I set them up a ssh access using `putty` and explained how to use it in order to access `local services`... it was the hardest thing I've ever done. to try to explain a sales man about computer that requires more than two steps **(DON'T DO IT, IT'LL KILL YOU)**...

anyways, I'm just wondering if there is any possibility what so ever that:

1. whenever they are in office, their browser **`automatically`** uses direct connections for ALL websites.
2. whenever they are outside the office, their browser uses a proxy `**ONLY**` for our `INTERAL services`.

please note, the clients ( salesMan laptop) are only **`Windows`**

Comment: Would it be possible to use Firefox? http://superuser.com/questions/417896/using-a-proxy-for-certain-sites-only There may be something similar for Chrome extensions.

Comment: @MC10 apparently there is a FoxyProxy for chrome, I'll check it and let you know, thx

Comment: Internet Explorer does this automatically..  If needed, you can look at the detail of the Advanced button for Proxy setup.  You can add additional IPs to be used when you are in the office, for example.

Comment: @MC10 mate I just check foxyProxy, it does not automatically create a connection to the server.